# How to use an iterating variable in a for loop in MS-DOS batch files?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a batch file which does something like this

```
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5) do dir > %%a.output
```

`%%a` just gives me a `.`

How can I use the value of the variable `%%a` to assign the file name (e.g. 1.output, 2.output) ?

Comment: Btw, what version of the command processor are you using? (What do you get when you enter 'ver' at the prompt?)

Comment: Are you entering/testing this by hand at a CMD prompt, or running a batch file?  It makes a difference.  Make sure you are not entering %% at the CMD prompt, but only in a BAT file.

Comment: Windows 98 [Version 4.10.2222]

Comment: MS-DOS didn't have the for command, as far as I know. Neither has Windows 9x. Batch files are hardly painless on Windows (NT and later) but on DOS/Win9x they are really painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to surround your variable:

```
for %a in (1 2 3 4 5) do dir > %a%.output
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command syntax looks correct to me. I would expect that line of a batch file, as is, to produce these commands:

```
dir > 1.output
dir > 2.output
dir > 3.output
dir > 4.output
dir > 5.output
```

Which would in turn create `1.output`, `2.output`, etc.

As a debugging tip, you might try changing that line to something like this:

```
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5) do echo dir ^> %%a.output
```

Note the `^`, which is used to escape the `>` redirection.

Also:

- Remember to use `%%a` in batch files
  but `%a` at the command line.
- Remember that `for` variables are
  case-sensitive; `%%A` is different
  from `%%a`.

**Update**

It's been a long time since I had to get a batch file working under such an old OS version, but I wouldn't be surprised if redirection was incompatible with `for` back in the day.

You could try this:

```
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5) do call helper.bat %%a
```

In helper.bat:

```
dir > %1.output
```

Or, if you don't like an extra batch file, combine them into one file:

```
if .%1==.sub goto do_sub
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5) do call %0 sub %%a
goto end
:sub
shift
dir > %1.output
:end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Win98 system at my disposal, but enter `for /?` in a DOS box and see if there's something there that can help you.

The way to do this in NT-based Windows OS is:

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]
```

So your statement would be something like:

```
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,5) DO echo dir ^> %%a.output
```

Perhaps there's something similar in DOS under Win98.